# Running appium android test in headless mode

Tags: android, unit-testing, ubuntu, android-emulator, appium

Appium tests can be run in headless mode by specifying the capability "isheadless"= true. However, the emulator still needs to be started before appium will work and we start the emulator in headless mode with the -no-window argument.

So I'm wondering, what's the point of specifying the is headless capability if we still need to specify it in the argument when starting the emulator. Will that appium session not work with the headless emulator without it?